# HTML Open html file when choose combobox item

Tags: javascript, html, combobox, web

I have this combobox on my web site, and I want it so upon choosing the English option it will open an html file called "index-eng.html", and upon choosing the Spanish option it will open an html file called "index-span.html".

How would I do this? Here is the code I've tried.

```
<option class="level-0" value="1"><a href="index-eng.html">English Inglés</a></option>
<option class="level-1" value="2"><a href="index-span.html">Spanish Español</a></option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an onchange event to the select.

```
<script>
function redirect()
{
window.location=document.getElementById('selectName').value;
}
</script>
<select id="selectName" onchange="redirect()">
<option value="index-eng.html">English</option>
<option value="index-span.html">Spanish</option>
</select>
```